# displaying data from restful service in react UI through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, reactjs

I've developed a restful webservice which displays a simple data using below code.

```
    package com.mike;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/message",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Message print(){
        return new Message(1,"Hello Mike!!");
    }
}
```

and the bean is as follows....

```
package com.mike;

public class Message {

    private int id;
    private String message;

    public Message(int id, String message){
        this.id=id;
        this.message=message;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMesssage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


}
```

now I want to display this data in an Nodejs application, so I wrote a file named app.js and wrote the following code to display data in the console.and it worked fine. but i don't know how to integrate this nodejs application with reactjs UI so that i can display in on a web page. so please kindly help me, I am new to both node and react.the code for app.js is below...

```
var http=require('http');

var extServerOptions={
    host:'localhost',
    port:'8080',
    path:'/message',
    method:'GET'
};

var mes=[];
var x;
var text="";

function get(){
    http.request(extServerOptions,function (res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data',function(data){
            mes=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(mes);
            for(x in mes){
                text+=mes[x]+" ";
            };
            console.log(text);
        });
        }).end();
    };
get();
```

please kindly say me the stepps i need to do in order to display data in a react page.

Comment: oh jeez this is a big question. You want to deliver the index.html file on a "catch-all" handler which will have the javascript to fetch at that endpoint, though, in concept.

Comment: probably like this, write React component, send Ajax request to NodeJS, which sends request to microservice in Java which the responds to NodeJS which in turn responds to Ajax call. I believe that is "too much" for a microservice which just returns a 'Hey Mike'. Or make use of `node-http-proxy` as a service which just proxies request to microservice.